# How to use the :last-child class to align my content at the bottom of my Navbar?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navbar

I would like to have a Dark(/light) Mode Tab on the bottom of my Navbar. This seems to be harder than I thought. Using `bottom:0` puts my content to the bottom of the page which is not what I want and using `margin-top: auto;` also doesn't seem to work at all. I am very new to this, sorry. Here's my simple HTML, for the sake lets ignore how light-mode will work with an html link anyway, planning on working on that later.

```css
nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  padding: .75rem;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid var(--color-green);
  padding: .5rem;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-color: var(--color-white);
  color: var(--color-white);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Vorstellungen.html">Vorstellungen</a></li>
    <li><a href="Trailer.html">Trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="Links.html">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="Light-Mode.html">Light-Mode</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is a problem with my grid, if yes I can post further Information on that. But all I need is basically my last list item to to be at the very bottom of my nav, not my page. Thanks for reading.

This is what it looks like without :last-child classes or bottom:0:
[image: This is what it looks like without :last-child classes or bottom:0]

Comment: And why would you want to use a grid for an ordinary Navigation Bar? Use FlexBox

Comment: my page consists of 6 Boxes, thought a grid would suffice. Would you suggest to always go with flexbox?

Comment: And it is better to also affix an image of the results you got, to make it easier for everyone

Comment: Grids are mostly used when a high-level layout is very hard to achieve. And nav bars are grouped together and they mostly stay together. FlexBoxes would be easier.

Comment: @noah alright I will try out flexbox for my page